# Django. Взаимодействие Python c html-объектами

Tags: javascript, python, django

Возможно ли в Django при помощи Phyton взаимодействовать с html-объектами на веб-странице чтобы обеспечить её интерактивность по принципам JavaScript? Или без JScript не обойтись в необходимых для этого случаях?

Comment: Без JS не обойтись.

Comment: Чтобы добиться иетерактивности в браузере, необходимо использовать браузерный яп. На текущий момент. - это бесповоротно js либо, если хотите, brython. Но он все равно будет компилировать в js. А на бэке у вас будет джанго-питон

Comment: Возможна ли в данном случае передача объектов из JavaScript непосредственно в Python, не используя базу данных?

Comment: @JBlack да. Как правило, обмен происходит в json-формате. Но возможны и другие как-то: обычный текст, xml, любой пользоватеский формат

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Интерактивность на вебстраницах обеспечивает javascript, на сегодняшний день. То есть нормальная технология для браузерного клиента - это HTML5.

В джанге же можно формировать сами страницы с помощью джанговского шаблонизатора - django-templates, и соответственно формировать её на основе сформированной на питоне информации.

В современной же веб-разработке чаще всего используется отдельно написанный клиент на html5, который общается с сервером с помощью текстовых сообщений, которые обычно представляют собой сериализованную, из объектов языка, информацию.